# Add MySQL Libarys in C# project

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I made an application that connects to a MySQL database, so it needs the MySQL libarys.
The problem is that it works on my PC but not on anyone elses. if I take the .exe from the debug folder (Which I see a lot of people do..) it cannot connect with mysql because it doesn't include the libarys.

I embedded all the images to it, is it possible to do the same thing with the mysql libarys?

I've been looking for hours.. Hopefully some one can help me! Thx..

Comment: You should have a dll in your debug folder...

Comment: Yes, but I want to send this project as one .exe file.

Comment: try [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to merge the dlls into the exe

Answer (score 0):

try in your solution / references / `mysql.data` see properties, and choose copy local = true,
does that another computer already has

> mysql data base?

Comment: Uhm, wait what? Copy Local was already to true.. And I've also seen an Embed option but it gives back errors. :/

Answer (score 0):

Since your references are .NET dlls, you can add them to the target exe using the [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) tool.

Hope I helped!